# Component as grid emptyText in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I want to display a component as `emptyText` for a grid, the [ExtJS documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-emptyText) states that only HTML can be shown.

For example a button that pop-ups a create window, as shown below:
[image]

Is there a workaround to use a component in a grid, or perhaps even a config that I'm missing?

Comment: No can do at the moment. You'll need to show some UI element elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do that, just that you will have to debug a lot in order to see how to do that. That's why I have an alternative: add a hidden docked toolbar with your "Create new employee" button. Then add an  listener for the `load` store event, and when no records are available, simply show the toolbar, otherwise hide the toolbar.

Comment: Excellent idea, I'll try it out; if there's no more alternatives I'll mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: Noticed an issue with the approach, mainly that the toolbar is stuck either above the columns or way below where the empty component should be. Sadly not really a solution as it stands. Any ideas?